# How to pop to root view controller

Tags: ios7, ios6

I have a question about pop to root view controller.

For example: A push to B, B present to C, C present to D. A is root view controller. Now I want D back to A. How to pop to this view controller? Can you help me? I also have found many questions relate to this but still have not found the answer for this.

Comment: I assume you have not even tried to find the solution, so why did you say such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [`UINavigationController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you can use [`popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated%3a). Assuming your UINavigationController is declared as `myNavigationController`:

```
[myNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```